# Importing multiple .cvs files into MATLAB without headers into separated matrices

Tags: matlab

I have 100 .csv files that I want to import as 100 matrices into MATLAB. Each file has six columns and the first four rows are headers. I need each matrix to be imported as six columns without the first four rows.

Example code would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post and include a few rows of your csv and an example of what you have tried already. (Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  for details).

Comment: Have a look at [dlmread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), you can specify a row offset. And, I would suggest to store your matrices in a struct using [dynamic field references](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) and not using `eval` as this is often proposed. Apart from that, full acknowledge with @kkuilla: Provide some own code before letting others do your work.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpfull for such operations is the Matlab import tool which you will find in the Home tab and use it to generate a import function (Matlab-Code).

This tool allows you to select the data you need graphically and declare the data format and the variable names. Instead of importing this data directly, you can generate a import function. This function you can use to import all 100 .csv files in a loop. Further you can alternate the code for more detailed import settings.

(Detailed Explanation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool-app.html)

Hope this helps, cheers